# Jenkins Gerrit-Trigger plugin: How to start build for each push instead of each commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

We are using Jenkins,GerritTrigger setup for CI and it will start build for each commit though all commits came from single push. Since all changes are dependent on each other its enough to make a single build with all changes, but I don't see that option in GerritTrigger plugin.

I believe many companies use Jenkins and Gerrit combination and I am curious to know how they are handling these cases.

Example:

If a developer pushes below 4 commits at once to gerrit it will create 4 changes accordingly in gerrit say 1,2,3,4 and it starts 4 builds in jenkins for all commit

```
git log --oneline

e3dfdwd CommitD
5fgfdgh CommitC
df34dsf CommitB
a23sdr3 CommitA
```

Here 4 commits as a whole will pass all tests in jenkins but individually they will fail. Now jenkins builds will fail for A, B, C and will succeed for D as it will checkout A,B,C as they are its dependencies.

In this case though Commit-D is successful it can't be merged as its dependencies are not passed in Jenkins.

It seems reasonable from development to expect jenkins verification for each push instead of each commit. But GerritTrigger can run for each commit only.

**Question:**

Is there a way to inform jenkins to start build only for commit-D as it will have all dependencies C,B,A ??
Or can we start a build for each git push from development instead of commits?

Sorry if I had any info

Comment: please explain why the developer wants to push 4 commits at a same time, or if there is no reason then just avoid it by squashing them

Comment: Pushing four commits at a time it very reasonable, but having unbuildable intermediate commits seems very misguided.

Comment: Yes MagnusBack you are right, we have to compromise on unbuildable intermediate commits in this approach. But depending on our work scenarios it seems reasonable and it reduces our resource consumption a lot, instead of doing 4 builds it will do only 1 build.

Comment: It will make sure entire code base is buildable and verified always but not each commit. We are fine with this and don't see any issues in our team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to start build only for commit-D.

I have introduced a gerrittrigger job which runs immediately after every commit, this job will not do any clone/build/verification.

It will just do some set of verifications like, check if given change has needed-by change, dependency exists and dependencies on same branch etc

This job will trigger another main job which does real clone, checkout change, build, verification etc only for changes which pass all validations.

So this will start job always for top commit and approve/reject all dependent changes based on job result.

Though it has few limitations, we found this method is suitable for our workflow

Answer (score 0):

Most companies don't use git and gerrit :)  Most companies don't even use git, unfortunately.  And most of the ones that do, don't use gerrit.  I've consulted for dozens of companies: two use git, and neither of them have even heard of gerrit.

I don't think it's possible to get gerrit to think of pushes as if they were commits.  Since each commit in a push can be separately reviewed and rejected, each commit has to be considered and built separately.  If you don't want it to work that way, gerrit might not be for you.

Instead, you should squash your related commits locally before pushing them to gerrit.  This will achieve the desired results.

Comment: Thnaks Paul for your quick response. Yes unfortunately not many companies use gerrit. I worked on big Android projects where gerrit being used aggressively and I was fascinated by its coolness. It made me to start using gerrit in current project.